# Download a binary file and save it as its original name on the disk

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a binary file and save it as its original name on the disk(Linux).

In the code, I always save the file in the same name "sample.bin".
I want the file to be saved in its original name as it appears in the HTTP request.

```
params = {'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'file': (hash)}
response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)

downloaded_file = response.content

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('/tmp/sample.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: With this type of problem it is best to add the following to your question: what is the expected result(what do you want to accomplish) and what is happening instead(error messages etc.)

Comment: Possibly related: [http download file name](//stackoverflow.com/q/13307499)

Comment: In the code attached to the question, I always save the file in the same name "sample.bin".
I want the file to be saved in its original name as it appears in the HTTP request.

Comment: HTTP request or response?

Comment: sorry, I mean to HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the response headers
something along the lines of

```
response.headers['content-disposition']
```

then pass the name variable to with open like

```
open('%s.bin', 'wb') %name
```

Comment: name = response.headers['content-disposition']
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'content-disposition'

Comment: print(response.headers) check if 'content-disposition' is a key your output will look like {'content-length': '12150', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'date': 'Thu, 05 Jan 2018 09:45:02 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'attachment; filename="example.bin"'}

Comment: Now looks OK but have another error:  
with open('%s.bin', 'wb') %name as f:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: '_io.BufferedWriter' and 'str'